# How to hide location of image in django?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    UID = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, default=datetime.now().strftime("%d%y%H%S%m%M"))  # default=
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, blank=False)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=MY_CHOICES)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, )
```

Forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdate(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('image', 'fullname', 'mobile', 'occupation', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'pincode')
```

Views.py

```
def user_settings(request):
    email = request.session['email']
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, email=email)
    form = ProfileUpdate(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'files/profileSettings.html', {'profileupdate': form, })
```

Html

```
 <div class="input-field col l7">
  {{ profileupdate.image }}
  </div>
```

My problem is that when I used above html tag for getting choose file for image.this field also shows the path of that file that is already exist.Because I used instance in view that automatic show user value.So I want to hide that location of image.I don't know what I search on google.

Comment: You can't hide the location of a linked resource from the HTML. Otherwise the browser won't be able to find the image either.

Comment: Now I have find solution of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput,)` in forms

```
class ProfileUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
        image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput,)
        class Meta:
            model = UserInfo
            fields = ('image', 'fullname', 'mobile', 'occupation', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'pincode')
```