# How to hide image from Django template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to make a blog website. On the all post page, it renders all the posts from the database. But not all post has its feature image. So, I'm trying to hide those image sections that don't have any featured images.

Here is **blog/model.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)
author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, null=False, db_index=True)
excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=60)
featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts", null=True, blank=True, default="default.jpg")
content = FroalaField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

Here is **blog/view.py**

```
# display all blog posts
def posts(request):
    all_posts = Article.published.all()
    context = {'all_posts': all_posts}
    return render(request, 'blog/posts.html', context)


# Single post
def single_post(request, slug):
    post = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/single-post.html', context)
```

Here is **blog/url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.posts, name="posts"),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.single_post, name="single-post"),
]
```

Here is **post.html**

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
<li class="bg-white px-4 py-6 shadow sm:p-6 sm:rounded-lg">
  <article aria-labelledby="question-title-81614">
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
      <!-- author details & option menus -->
      <div class="flex space-x-3">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <!-- author image -->
          <img
            class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
            src="{{ post.author.profile.avatar.url }}"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <!-- author name and publish date time -->
        <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
          <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
            <a href="#" class="hover:underline">Dries Vincent</a>
          </p>
          <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
            <time datetime="{{ post.publish.date }}"
              >{{ post.publish.date }}
            </time>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-4 space-y-4">
        {# show image if there is a feature image #}

        {% if post.featured_image.url %}

        <!-- article images -->
        <img
          class="object-cover w-full h-64 bg-center rounded-lg"
          src="{{ post.featured_image.url }}"
          alt="{{ post.title }}"
        />

        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <!-- article title -->
      <h1
        id="question-title-81614"
        class="mt-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900"
      >
        {{ post.title }}
      </h1>
    </a>
  </article>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the image for a better understanding
[post.html template page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOE3o.png)

Comment: [link to another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320035/how-to-hide-location-of-image-in-django#37327833)

Comment: This looks more like a wrong default, if no image is provided you should set it to `None`/`NULL`: `featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts", null=True, blank=True, default=None)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a wrong default, if no image is provided you should set it to `None`/`NULL`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

you can then render it with a condition like:

```
{% if post.featured_image %}
    <!-- article images -->
    <img
        class="object-cover w-full h-64 bg-center rounded-lg"
        src="{{ post.featured_image.url }}"
        alt="{{ post.title }}"
    />
{% endif %}
```

You can set the `Article`s with a `default.jpg` to `None` for example with a query in the Django shell:

```
Article.objects.filter(
    featured_image='default.jpg'
).update(featured_image=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

While defining your model, `null=True` and `Blank=True` also set the default to `None`.

If you're going to render Alf those that have `featured_picture`, you'll need to add a little if `post.featured_picture`, or whatever your image field is named, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if post.featured_image.url == "/media/default.jpg" %}
                        
   <!-- <h1>Data Not Exist</h1> -->

{% else %}

   {{ post.featured_image.url }} 
                            
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details, what does it do? How does it solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!