# HTML show image if it exists and show nothing if it doesn't

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I need to display an image on my HTML page but only if it exists on my computer (aka i give it a path and it checks). If it doesn't, then show nothing. How can I write a function that checks if the image exists, then if yes, display it if no, don't show anything?
I am using django as a back end.

Comment: _"if it exists in my directory"_ where is this directory? On your local machine? What's checking for the image? Please may you share some code/[mcve]?

Comment: Hi. I generate images from data (using Django), and when there's no image available in my "folder", then I don't want it to show anything. Instead, it gives an error that the file doesn't exist. this is what I have in my HTML:
`  <img src="{%static '/snippets/images/graph.jpg'%}"/>`
sorry that I worded it wrong English is not my native

Comment: `<img onerror="this.remove()" .../>`

Comment: Or just use an [if in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077324/how-to-hide-image-from-django-template)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [os.path.exist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-exists-method/?ref=lbp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).